# Parallax + Multiple Background animation

Tags: css, magento, animation, background, parallax

I'm working on customization of some magento theme. Please let me know if there's anything else you need to know, I'm new to this game.

Here's what need to go:

Have each section:
1) Resize: Automatically resize to full-screen

2) Animate: Multiple background animation (Fixed background image with clouds.PNG moving from right to left)

3) Parallax: Parallax with fade effect as you scroll up and down.

Demo of Full screen and Parallax:

Demo of passing cloud over an image could be seen:
www.hacksummit.org

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please create a specific question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we are a community designed to solve specific problems, you can't come here and ask people to write code for you or do your job. It is expected that you put some effort in researching and attempting to solve your "problem". If your attempted approaches fail or are not working as expected then you would share your code with us and the community will try to tell you what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I'll be mindful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! As per comments - stack overflow is for specific questions! However, I'll happily drop a link or two so you've got a fighting chance:

Responsive design:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

CSS Animation:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Parallax done right:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/parallax/

p.s. all of those websites are gold!!!

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I was able to get the done although a bit differently.

Comment: Now, I'm experiencing another issue regarding application.